# Delete all rows below the last row of data for import process from Access

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Microsoft Excel 2010:
From month to month, the number of lines of data can be variable. When I paste new data into the ILS_IMPORT tab, there may be 3,500 records and the next month could be 2,500. When I go to import the data into Access, and extra 1,000 lines will appear unless I delete all records from line 2,501 on. I would like to have Excel VBA to do this and have made attempts, but nothing has worked thus far. I know that Column O will always have data to the end because it is the quarter indicator (ex. Q2).

[image: ILS_IMPORT tab]

However, this code keeps deleting the last row and I don't know if it is truly deleting all the way to the end. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 Sub test()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim lastRow As Long


 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ILS_IMPORT")
    'Find anything in the cells
   Set rng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("O1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False)
    'if data is NOT found - exit from sub
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'find last row
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("O1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastRow = 1
    End If
    'I use lastRow + 1 to prevent deletion data above when it is on lastrow
    .Range(rng.Row + 2 & ":" & lastRow + 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
   End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of your last line (`.Range(rng.row+2 & ...`) try `.Range(.Cells(rng.Row+2,1),.Cells(lastRow+2,1)).EntireRow.Delete`.  I think as you have it now, the system is just seeing like "Range(2:4)" and may not be as accurate as using the Range(cells(),cells()).

Comment: @user3578951 That still deletes that last row of my data.

Comment: If you change `.Cells(lastRow+2,1))...` to `.Cells(lastRow-1,1))`?  I would mess with that part, and determine what the "lastRow" keeps being determined as, and then just do -1 instead of +2?

Comment: @user3578951 Seemingly it is deleting the #1 #2 line, I decided to color the lines to see what is going on. Hence, the code isn't even establishing the last row of data. Man this can get frustrating at times. Thanks for your tutelage though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you clear/delete the blank range before you paste data in?

```
range(cells(2,1),cells(2,1).end(xldown)).EntireRow.Clear
```

Comment: I was looking into circumventing and doing this very thing and then you suggested it. Nice and thanks! It works

Comment: I saved the file and when I went back to make sure before deployment it fails again.
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ILS_IMPORT").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Clear`
Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error
Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: I got this to work:
`With Worksheets("ILS_IMPORT")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
               .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete
               Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ILS_IMPORT").Range("A1"))
        MsgBox "The data has been deleted and you are now ready for the next step.", vbOKOnly

        Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Range("A1"))
    End With`